# MYSQL sum a count value or sum a name value

Tags: mysql

I need to find a way to count a name value and then sum it.

There are 2 tables with information. they got a relationship with each other (foreign key).

For each customer, he shows their payment_method
The select statement:

```
select payment_method
from Customer
```

output:

```
payment_method
Mastercard
Visa
Amex
etc...

select payment_method
from Payment
```

output:

```
Amex
Mastercard
Visa
```

So I need to find how many customers use a payment_method

So the output that I want from my SQL-statement:
Payment_method:

```
Amex           60 (people are using this)
Mastercard     80(people are using this)
Visa           120(people are using this)
```

The output is just an example of what it should look for my view

The statements that i tried are:

```
SELECT payment_method
ROUND (
(
LENGTH(payment_method)
- LENGTH ( REPLACE ( description, "value", "" ) ) 
) / LENGTH ("value")
) AS count
FROM customer
```

but this didn't work it gave a error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is an **aggregation query**. Aggregate functions operate on a set of values.

Here, our aggregation function is a `count()` as we're trying to count **all** the matching rows in each bucket denoted by `payment_id`.

```sql
select payment_method, count(*) as count from customer
     group by payment_method;
```

Comment: Oh, thanks! It worked and it the solution was I was looking for. So if I understand it correctly in this statement we count twice the payment_method and if both rows are the same output he +1 as an example on visa

Comment: Essentially, we group by payment_method first. This gives you distinct set of rows in each bucket. If you have 15 customers of which 8 use Amex, 6 use Visa and 1 uses Mastercard, and you group by payment method, then you'll have 3 buckets of data. This is where grouping ends. It serves no useful purpose on its own.   

The useful part is where you define a function that knows how to deal with the rows in each group. Here, we summed because you were looking for overall count. It could have been any function. Read about them: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html